# How to fix this weird corrupted pdf issue

Tags: pdf, pdflib

We process a lot of incoming pdfs, by extracting their pages into separate files. And sometimes we encounter this weird problem. Every extracted page will be almost the size of the entire file.
For example if pdf is 500 Mb and has 1000 pages, then extracting separate pages from it will result in 1000 files each 500 mb. Even though when opening the separate page files you can only see one page there.

When we use Adobe Acrobat feature Reduce File Size, Adobe Acrobat takes some time and produces a smaller file. And after that the problem of extracting pages is fixed. The pages start extracting correctly and have small sizes.

We've encountered a few files so far and probably will encounter more.

I've tried to look for a tool to automatically repair such files and we downloaded and tried Pdflib PLOP tool. Unfortunately it did not fix the file, even though i selected all applicable repair and optimize options. Here's the command line i used:

~/plop -v 4 --inputopt "xmppolicy=remove repair=force" --outputopt optimize=all --outfile fixed.pdf bad.pdf

It did not fix the problem at all.

Have you ever encountered such problems? And do you have an example of how to fix them using pdflib library or any other library or tool?

Comment: How is this a programming question? At the very best, it's a general software question that is more suitable for [su]. At the worst, it's a request for a tool recommendation, which according to the [help/on-topic] is specifically off-topic here.

Comment: The solution for this problem may be in some library, like pdflib. And the solution is needed in automation (not manual work) So best answer is the programming answer. That's why it is here and not in SuperUser

Comment: Your question says nothing about programming, and we can't recommend a tool or library. You need to rephrase your question or move it to [su].

Answer (score 1):

The reason why such files are *not fixed* by pdf repair programs is that they are *not broken* to start with. They merely are built in a way that makes simple pdf splitters copy all resources (images, fonts, ...) from the source pdf into each split pdf.

**In more detail,** a pdf is built from many objects, primitive ones like strings and numbers and more complex ones like arrays and dictionaries.

Each page is represented by a dictionary referenced from the pages tree. These page dictionaries reference their respective content streams which contain the instructions for building the page. These instructions are not all self contained, though, they may refer to resources like fonts and bitmap images by name. Such resources are looked up in a resource dictionary which also is referenced from the page dictionary.

But a resource dictionary is not required to only contain resources for the very page it is referenced from, there may be more and such extra entries which are not used on the page simply are ignored while drawing it.

This allows **pdf producers** to simply put *all resources for the whole pdf* into a *single resource dictionary* which then is referenced by all page dictionaries, and some pdf producers indeed do so. Pdfs built like this are the pdfs troubling you.

On the other hand **pdf splitters** usually *assume* that the resource dictionary referenced from a page only contains the resources for that very page and, therefore, simply copy the whole resource dictionary into the split file for the page.

In case of pdfs built using a single resource dictionary this results in all source pdf resources being copied for each page, and as usually the resources contain the big data blobs, the resulting split files for each page are each nearly as big as the source file.

To return to the focus of stack overflow, programing, what one needs to implement is a routine that

- reads a pdf,
- for each page parses the content streams for used resource names,
- replaces the respective resource dictionary of each page by one that only contains the entries used on that page, and
- stores this changed pdf again.

Applying such a program to a pdf before splitting should prevent the issue at hand.

---

P.S.: the situation actually is a bit more complicated as not only pages have resource dictionaries but also other entities like annotations, form XObjects, and patterns. These have to be processed likewise. Furthermore, page information may not only appear in the page dictionary itself but can also be inherited from ancestors up to the root of the pages tree. But these are mere details...